# Why is every derivation a Lie derivation and every Lie derivation is a Lie triple derivation?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, lie-derivative

I’m studying Lie triple derivation of triangular algebra.. I know what is Lie derivation and what is Lie triple derivation but I am not getting the sense that why every derivation is a lie derivation and every lie derivation is a lie triple derivation ? But the converse is not true.
Can you please help me in understanding this thing. Explaining with any relevant example will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A Lie triple derivation is by definition just a *pre-derivation*, i.e., a linear map $P\colon L\rightarrow L$ satisfying
$$
P([x,[y,z]])=[P(x),[y,z]]+[x,[P(y),z]]+[x,[y,P(z)]]$$
for every $x,y,z\in L$. Of course, every ordinary derivation is a pre-derivation:
Let $D\in Der(L)$. Then by definition
$$D([x,[y,z]])=[x,D([y,z])]+[D(x),[y,z]]$$
Substituting $D([y,z])=[D(y),z]+[y,D(z)]$ we obtain
$$D([x,[y,z]])=[x,[D(y),z]]+[x,[y,D(z)]]+[D(x),[y,z]].$$
The converse is not true in general. Take the Heisenberg Lie algebra.

Comment: Why call it "pre-derivation"? "Lie triple derivation" is a much more explicit, and more flexible terminology.

Comment: @YCor This is not my terminology; it comes from geometry, see the paper *Isometries of bi-invariant pseudo-Riemannian metrics on Lie groups* by Detlef Müller. See also my paper [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_14_preder.pdf).